# Infinite scroll when scrolled to the middle of the page

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have some list of products and they end in the middle of the page. I need to load more products from API when the user scrolled to the end of the products, i.e. to the middle of the page. I wrote the code that enables that feature, but the problem is, that when I scrolled to the bottom, function colled several times(this is expected behavior). How to call function ONES when I scrolled to the end of the products. And the second issue, how to define the direction of the scroll event, i.e. I need to make API request when user scrolling top to bottom and gets to the end of the products.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  if(this.isInViewport){
      //api request
      }
  })

isInViewport(){
  const bounding = this.$refs.button.getBoundingClientRect();
      return (
         bounding.top >= 0 &&
         bounding.left >= 0 &&
         bounding.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || 
         document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
         bounding.right <= (window.innerWidth || 
         document.documentElement.clientWidth));
}
```

I expect to make API request ONCE per end of the products

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is awesome built-in API called Intersection Observer API
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

It can help you, but its not supported throughout all the browsers.

Anyways you can modify your own code by something like this:

```
let requestSend = false

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  if(this.isInViewport && !requestSend){
      requestSend = true;

      //api request
      ApiRequest().then(() => requestSend = false);
      }
  })
```

Comment: Intersection Observer API solved my problem! Thanks, dude